# Javascript set input value after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div with generated input fields. After button click I want to refresh div and then set values.

```
<div>
  <input id="1" name="1" type="text" />
  <input id="2" name="2" type="text" />
</div>
<button type="button" onClick="change();">Change</button>
```

Javascript function:

```
function change(){
  $('div').load(' div');
  $("input[type='text']").val("some text");            
}
```

Why after load I can't set values for input? How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: You could just call `change()` on load of the DOM...? Also, what are you expecting `load(' div')` to do, as it's not a valid usage of the `load()` method.

Comment: I need to refresh div because count of input fields are generated by server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` is *asynchronous*.  So when you do this:

```
$('div').load(' div');
$("input[type='text']").val("some text");
```

That second line executes *before the content has been loaded*.  In order to respond to the completion of the content being loaded, you need to use the callback function:

```
$('div').load(' div', function () {
    $("input[type='text']").val("some text");
});
```